# F# infix overload doesn't work

Tags: f#

```
let (->>>) lst exp = for i in lst do exp

let result = [0..5] ->>> ([1..5] ->>> printf "hi")
let result2 = for i in [0..5] do for x in [1..5] do printf "hi"
```

I was expecting `result` and `result2` to do the same thing. But result prints hi just once. `result2`, however, prints it 30 times. What is missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your operator definition, `exp` is not necessarily a function. The way you defined the operator, `exp` is any value whatsoever. For example, you could do this:

```
[0..1] ->>> 42
```

This would compile and even run, because there is nothing in the definition of your operator that requires the `exp` parameter to be a function. Or anything else for that matter.

If you want to make `exp` evaluate over and over within the body of the loop, you need to make it a function and make sure that the body of the loop calls it. Since you don't have any requirements for it, the simplest one would be `unit -> 'a`. You don't really have to declare its type though, you can have the compiler infer it from its use:

```
let (->>>) lst exp = for i in lst do exp()
```

Notice the parentheses after `exp` - they signify a value of type `unit`, thus making expression `exp()` a function application (i.e. function `exp` applied to value `()`).

Of course, with this definition, you won't be able to write `[1..5] ->>> printf "hi"`, because `printf "hi"` is not a function. So instead you'll have to write:

```
[1..5] ->>> (fun() -> printf "hi")
```

Now you'll have five "hi"s printed out.

This is because the `for .. do` syntax is really a special part of the language, not "just another function" defined in the standard library. You can't really create same effect with clever function or operator definitions.

If you want a way to construct more complicated syntax than functions and operators, check out [computation expressions](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer is well appreciated.

Comment: A more real-life solution would be to make the lambda to receive an element: `... do exp i`. This would make it possible to use `printf "hi %d"`, and it does not even need a clumsy `fun i -> ` wraparound